# neo4j date was indexed as string (import tool) and using apoc for parsing queries is good approach?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Date fields were indexed  as string (import tool) and using apoc for parsing queries is good approach? 
How it's affect performance?
What's the best approach?
Be aware that my initial load is from import tool 
Thanks
in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to store your dates as integers  representing milliseconds since epoch (milliseconds passed since 01-01-1970 00:00:00:00). It has some advantages:

- Easy to compare: You do not need to convert the dates before comparing since it is a simple number. So to verifiy if the birth date of `a` is greater to birth date of `b` you simply do `a.birthDate > b.birthDate`.
- Without dependencies: You will not depend on any library to compare your dates.
- Since you are storing your dates as an simple integer you can convert it in the front-end application and present it in any format you choose.

Also when you need you will use the APOC procedures to manipulate the timestamps stored in the database.

Comment: If the source of the data is in time format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss it's better to convert it before loading to neo4j or it's ok to convert while loading ?what about impact on the performance of loading

Comment: it depends where you want to put the time of the conversion, in your extract or in your load ? The impact on the ETL chain will be the same.